# I want to clarify some things about IP Datagram and Ping

Tags: ip, protocols, ping, datagram

Are datagrams a protocol or not? 
Is "Ping" (protocol ICMP) used in an IP DATAGRAM? Or is it using other protocols, such as TCP or UDP?
How do you know the message "Reply"  the way back? 
Why the Tel number stays the same?

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Protocol

Datagrams are basically the packets that go back an forth over the network at IP level. Each of these packets can specify a protocol. You can have TCP, UDP, ICMP, etc. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers)

So to answer your question, yes the protocol for datagrams is basically IP.
You can have higher level protocols that run over IP such the one above.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite

Ping uses the ICMP protocol.

Comment: The Datagrams is the protocol or no ? yes or no ? @Mircea thanx

Comment: No. the IP protocol uses datagram (i.e. packets) to exchange information. read on IP and TCP/IP

Comment: Ok ,  Ping  used the protocol UDP ? yes or no ? and thanx @Mircea

Comment: the head of ICMP = the head of Protocol IP 
and the data protocole ICMP !=  data protocole IP  
yeah ?  @Mircea

Comment: ICMP is the body of IP. go through the wikipedia article to understand the TCP/IP stack model and how things are glued together

Comment: hahaaha thanx yopii , 
the Last question ! 
What features found in ICMP ?

Answer (score 0):

> Are datagrams a protocol or no?

'Datagram' is the name of the unit of transmission in the UDP protocol.

> Is "Ping" ( protocol ICMP ) used in a IP DATAGRAM?

The question doesn't make sense. It would make more sense to say that the ICMP protocol is transmitted via IP packets.

> Or is it using other protocols, such as TCP or UDP ?

ICMP *is* a protocol: you said so yourself; and it is layered over the IP protocol.